# Causal Impact: how to show all data points in predicted series?

Tags: r, causalimpact

This might be a very basic code question, but thank you for your help. I have used the Causal Impact package to run a regression on a data set with 144 monthly observations, cutting at point 88. I want to be able to see all the predicted data points, both pre and post intervention (i.e. the data for the dotted blue line in the plot), but I am not sure of the code in R to display this.

The code for the model so far is:

```
library(CausalImpact)
setwd("C:/Users/...")
mydata <- read.csv(file="revisionx.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
pre.period <- c(1, 87)
post.period <- c(88, 144)
model.args = list(nseasons = 48, season.duration = 3)
impact <- CausalImpact(mydata, pre.period, post.period)
plot(impact)
summary(impact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CausalImpact` object returns a list with four objects.

These are:

- series
- summary
- report
- model

You can find out more in the documentation `?CausalImpact` in the console.

I think what you want is the first one here:

```
impact[[1]] # series
impact[[2]] # summary
impact[[3]] # report
impact[[4]] # model
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.